# Error in ordering the X axis in Highchart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I hope somebody can help me! Well, I'm making a  Column chart using Highcharts. But, I don't know why, sometimes the chart have problems to render the date values in correct order... Look:

```
var dados1 = [
{name: 'Parameter 1', data: [ [Date.UTC(2015,3,23,12,25),0.77],], type: 'column', tooltip: { valueDecimals: 2}},{name: 'Parameter 2', data: [ [Date.UTC(2015,3,22,16,25),0.74],[Date.UTC(2015,3,30,16,25),0.74],], type: 'column', tooltip: { valueDecimals: 2}},];
var val_superior = 2;
var val_inferior = 0.20;
var maior_leitura = 2;
var menor_leitura = 0;
$(function () {
        Highcharts.setOptions({
            credits: {
                enabled: false
            },
            chart: {
                events: {
                    load: function () {
                        var chart = this;
                        var extremes = chart.xAxis[0].getExtremes();
                        chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes(extremes.min - (15 * 60 * 1000), extremes.max + (15 * 60 * 1000));
                    }
                }
            },
            //0000fe
            colors: ['#7cb5ec', '#434348', '#90ed7d', '#f7a35c', '#8085e9', '#f15c80', '#e4d354', '#8085e8', '#8d4653', '#91e8e1']            });
        // Create the chart
        $('#container').highcharts( {

            rangeSelector: {

                enabled: false
            },

            navigator: {
                enabled: false
            },
            title: {
                text: ''
            },
            legend: {
                enabled: true,
                align: 'center',
                backgroundColor: '#FCFFC5',
                borderColor: 'black',
                borderWidth: 1,
                layout: 'vertical',
                verticalAlign: 'top',
                y: 0,
                shadow: true
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Valores'
                },
                max: maior_leitura,
                min: menor_leitura,
                showEmpty: true,
                plotLines: [{
                    value: val_superior, //maior_leitura
                    id: 'linhaLimiteSuperior',
                    color: 'green',
                    dashStyle: 'shortdash',
                    width: 2,
                    label: {
                        text: 'Limite superior'
                    },
                    zIndex: 99
                }, {
                    value: val_inferior, //menor_leitura
                    id: 'linhaLimiteInferior',
                    color: 'red',
                    dashStyle: 'shortdash',
                    width: 2,
                    label: {
                        text: 'Limite inferior'
                    },
                    zIndex: 99
                }]
            },
            xAxis: {
                type: 'datetime'
            },
            series: dados1


        });

    });
```

The "Parameter 1" has 1 datetime value: April 23.
The "Parameter 2" has 2 datetime values: April 22 and April 30.

But if you see in the JSFiddle result, the Axis X is not in correct ordering... It must be: Parameter 2 (April 22), Parameter 1 (April 23) and Parameter 2 (April 30)
But it is: Parameter 1 (April 23), Parameter 2 (April 22) and Parameter 2 (April 30)

http://jsfiddle.net/atilaca/bjxp81x8/4/

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This looks like two issues happening:

1) the default grouping function for columns series is interfering with proper layout

2) the pointRange not being set is confusing the layout as well.

To solve, set grouping false, and pointRange appropriately:

```
plotOptions: {
  column: {
    grouping: false,
    pointRange: 86400 * 1000 //one day
  }
}
```

Example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/bjxp81x8/5/